# Como Unir Arreglos En C#

Tags: c#

Necesito unir 2 Arreglos tipo string y que quede todos los datos en un solo arreglo  me suena que se puede hacer pero yo no se como poder lograr esto

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dos métodos más, haciendo uso del método `Concat` y además una forma adicional , creando un arreglo con la `longitud de la primera cadena + longitud de la segunda` luego copiamos desde la posición 0 el primer arreglo , y el segundo arreglo a partir de la posición del final de la primera cadena todo esto haciendo uso del método `CopyTo`

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "HOLA" };
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "MUNDO" };


string[] result= arr.Concat(arr1).ToArray();

string[] result = new string[arr.Length + arr1.Length];
arr.CopyTo(result, 0);
arr1.CopyTo(result, arr.Length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo puedes hacer con lo siguiente usando [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
string[] result = array1.Union(array2).ToArray();
```

debes tener cuidado porque `union` elimina los datos repetidos.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede hacer por medio de una lista:

```
int[] arreglo1 = new int [] { 1, 2, 3};
int[] arreglo2 = new int [] { 6, 7, 9};

List<int> lista = new List<int>();  //declaración de la lista
lista.AddRange(arreglo1);           //utilizar metodo AddRange para cada arreglo
lista.AddRange(arreglo2);
int[] z = lista.ToArray();     //conviertes la lista a arreglo
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola tengo una pregunta quizás muy tonta tengo un rich text box que ocupará mil datos string y esos datos que pueden variar quiero almacenarlos en un arreglo (array) con la finalidad de que cuando quiera buscarlo lo pueda hacer solo colocando el número del array dónde está ubicado por ejemplo el 499 y que lo muestre en mi segundo rich text box. Agradecido con la ayuda

Comment: Hola @Kvin y bienvenido a [es.so]. Las preguntas no se hacen en la sección de respuestas, entèrate [ask], y de paso realiza el [tour].